# Checking hardware acceleration in the Transcoding sample application(Metro UI)

Tags: microsoft-metro

In the Sample Example provided by the Microsoft(Transcoding Sample Application) I need to check whether the Hardware Acceleration is enabled or not. for that I am using the code

**var hardwareAccelerationEnabled = mediaTranscoder.hardwareAccelerationEnabled;
mediaTranscoder.hardwareAccelerationEnabled = hardwareAccelerationEnabled;**

but while compiling it is showing the following error:

**JavaScript runtime error: 'mediaTranscoder' is undefined**

Kindly help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of the MediaTranscoder object first using "new". Example below:

```
var mediaTranscoder = new Windows.Media.Transcoding.MediaTranscoder();
var hardwareAccelerationEnabled = mediaTranscoder.hardwareAccelerationEnabled;
```